# Flutter: Mapbox onMapCreated not called in widget test

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, mapbox-gl, widget-test-flutter

I'm using the Mapbox map and when I run the app in an emulator, it works fine. However, in my widget test, the `onMapCreated` method is never called, which makes it impossible to test the behavior of the app.

My MapWidget (condensed):

```dart
class MapWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final LatLng initialCameraPositionCoordinates;
  final double initialZoomLevel;

  const MapWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.initialCameraPositionCoordinates,
    @required this.initialZoomLevel,
   }) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  State createState() => MapWidgetState();
}

class MapWidgetState extends State<MapWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<Cubit, State>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return MouseRegion(
          cursor: MouseCursor.defer,
          child: MapboxMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
}

void _onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) async {
    print("This is never called in the test");
}
```

And the corresponding widget test looks like this:

```dart
void main() {
    testWidgets("Mapbox", (WidgetTester tester) async {
        await tester.pumpWidget(
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => _cubit,
            child: MaterialApp(
              home: MapWidget(
                initialCameraPositionCoordinates:
                    _initialCameraPositionCorrdinates,
                initialZoomLevel: _initialZoomLevel,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
        await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 10));
      });
}
```

No exception is thrown, meaning it renders fine. However, the print statement in the `onMapCreated` is never printed.

Running the app in an emulator, the print statement is called.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what happened @bear?

Comment: Not really. I just accepted that in widget tests, the actual “content” of a `MapboxMap` widget is never created and the function will never be called.

Comment: Thank you for responding, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and worked around it by manually invoking the callbacks. Something like this in your widget test:

```dart
var mapboxMap = tester.firstWidget(find.byType(MapboxMap)) as MapboxMap;
mapboxMap.onMapCreated!(<mocked controller>);
mapboxMap.onStyleLoadedCallback!();
```

Where "<mocked controller" is an instance of your `MapboxMapController` mock.

I imagine the underlying issue has to do with the native map view not actually being loaded during widget tests, and therefore, no callbacks are invoked.